# How to load a .graphql file using `apollo-server`?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am currently loading the GraphQL schema using a separate `.graphql` file, but it is encapsulated within strings:

`schema.graphql`

```
const schema = `
  type CourseType {
    _id: String!
    name: String!
  }

  type Query {
    courseType(_id: String): CourseType
    courseTypes: [CourseType]!
  }
`

module.exports = schema
```

Then using it for the `apollo-server`:

`index.js`

```js
const { ApolloServer, makeExecutableSchema } = require('apollo-server')
const typeDefs = require('./schema.graphql')

const resolvers = { ... }

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: typeDefs,
  resolvers
})

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: schema
})

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`Server ready at ${url}.`)
})
```

Is there any way to simply load a .graphql that looks as such?
`schema.graphql`

```
type CourseType {
  _id: String!
  name: String!
}

type Query {
  courseType(_id: String): CourseType
  courseTypes: [CourseType]!
}
```

Then it would be parsed in the `index.js`? I noticed that `graphql-yoga` supports this, but was wondering if `apollo-server` does. I cannot find it anywhere in the docs. I can't get `fs.readFile` to work either.

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag#importing-graphql-files

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you define your type definitions inside a `.graphql` file, you can read it in one of several ways:

1.) Read the file yourself:

```
const { readFileSync } = require('fs')

// we must convert the file Buffer to a UTF-8 string
const typeDefs = readFileSync(require.resolve('./type-defs.graphql')).toString('utf-8')
```

2.) Utilize a library like `graphql-tools` to do it for you:

```
const { loadDocuments } = require('@graphql-tools/load');
const { GraphQLFileLoader } = require('@graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader');

// this can also be a glob pattern to match multiple files!
const typeDefs = await loadDocuments('./type-defs.graphql', { 
    file, 
    loaders: [
        new GraphQLFileLoader()
    ]
})
```

3.) Use a [babel plugin](https://github.com/detrohutt/babel-plugin-import-graphql) or a [webpack loader](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag#webpack-loading-and-preprocessing)

```
import typeDefs from './type-defs.graphql'
```

Comment: This is amazing! No way there's an equivalent `GraphQLFileLoader` method from `apollo-server`?

Comment: Maybe in a future version.

Comment: It should be noted that `readFileSync` only returns a string if you specify an encoding, eg: `const typeDefs = readFileSync('./schema.graphql', 'utf-8')`. If you do not include an encoding, it returns as a Buffer which ApolloServer's constructor does not understand.

Comment: thank you for noting about `'utf-8'` in `readFileSync`, I would have missed that

Comment: @DanielRearden I am getting this error when loading a subgraph schema in a federated graph ```ts
Unknown directive "@key".

Cannot extend type "Membership" because it is not defined.

Unknown directive "@key".

Unknown directive "@external".

Unknown type "Query".
```

Comment: @Hazem Alabiad I used the 1st option from this answer and wrapped it within `gql` for the federated subgraph. `const typeDefs = gql(readFileSync(require.resolve('./schema.graphql')).toString('utf-8'));`

Comment: @DanielRearden where is the file variable coming from in the 2nd example ie in the graphql-tools example

Comment: @DanielRearden did you get this working with Apollo Server-I tried the graphql-tools method with Apollo server, but getting this error: " Unable to find any GraphQL type definitions for the following pointers" - wondering if you need to do anything extra to get it working with Apollo Server

Answer (score 2):

Back in the day I wrote a teeny-tiny `.graphql` loader myself. It is very small, very simple, and the only thing you have to do is import it before you try to import any `.graphql` files. I have used it ever since even though I am sure that there are some 3rd party loaders available. Here's the code:

```
// graphql-loader.js

const oldJSHook = require.extensions[".js"];

const loader = (module, filename) => {
  const oldJSCompile = module._compile;
  module._compile = function (code, file) {
    code = `module.exports = \`\r${code}\`;`;
    module._compile = oldJSCompile;
    module._compile(code, file);
  };
  oldJSHook(module, filename);
};

require.extensions[".graphql"] = loader;
require.extensions[".gql"] = loader;
```

And then in your app:

```
// index.js

import "./graphql-loader"; // (or require("./graphql-loader") if you prefer)
```

That's it, you can then `import typeDefs from "./type-defs.graphql"` wherever you want.

The loader works by wrapping the text in your `.graphql` file inside a template string and compiling it as a simple JS module:

```
module.exports = ` ...your gql schema... `;
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

//function that imports .graphql files
const importGraphQL = (file) =>{
  return fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, file),"utf-8");
}

const gqlWrapper = (...files)=>{
  return gql`${files}`;
}


const enums = importGraphQL('./enums.graphql');
const schema = importGraphQL('./schema.graphql');

module.exports = gqlWrapper(enums,schema);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this helper:

```js
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
const requireGQL = (file) =>
  gql`${readFileSync(require.resolve(file)).toString("utf-8")}`;
```

Throw that at the top of your file and you can just:

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({ uri: 'https://myendpoint.com/graphql' });
const { data } = await client.query({ query: requireGQL("./myquery.gql") });
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using `fs` (thanks to Tal Z):

`index.js`

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const mongoUtil = require('./mongoUtil')
const { ApolloServer, makeExecutableSchema } = require('apollo-server')

function readContent (file, callback) {
  fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, content) => {
    if (err) return callback(err)
    callback(null, content)
  })
}

mongoUtil.connectToServer((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB.', error.stack)
    process.exit(1)
  }

  console.log('Connected to database.')

  const Query = require('./resolvers/Query')

  const resolvers = {
    Query
  }

  readContent('./schema.graphql', (error, content) => {
    if (error) throw error

    const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
      typeDefs: content,
      resolvers
    })

    const server = new ApolloServer({
      schema: schema
    })

    server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
      console.log(`Server ready at ${url}.`)
    })
  })
})
```

`schema.graphql`

```
type CourseType {
  _id: String!
  name: String!
}

type Query {
  courseType(_id: String): CourseType
  courseTypes: [CourseType]!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking for the Apollo documentation for this question here it is: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/workflow/generate-types

It describes using `readFileSync` like many answers here, but I was having trouble finding where they actually describe this method. Here's the snippet as well:

```
// ...other imports

import { readFileSync } from 'fs';


// Note: this uses a path relative to the project's

// root directory, which is the current working directory

// if the server is executed using `npm run`.

const typeDefs = readFileSync('./schema.graphql', { encoding: 'utf-8' });


const server = new ApolloServer<MyContext>({

  typeDefs,

  resolvers,

});


// ... start our server
```