# I'm unable to import schema.graphql file in typeDefs : Unable to find any GraphQL type definitions for the following pointers:

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

I'm using apollo-server-express to create backend apis with GraphQL

Now, I want to Write GraphQL Schema in a separate file. e.g. "schema.graphql", So when I put the same code as I wrote in Template String before. into the "schema.graphql" My application is crashed with below error:

> Unable to find any GraphQL type definitions for the following pointers

[image: Error Image]
<sub>(source: [googleapis.com](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/testingfirebase-7eb53.appspot.com/o/StackOverflow%2FUnable%20to%20Import%20.graphql%20file.jpg?alt=media&token=c19b7848-2489-4a6e-b7b5-195f52c55e53))</sub>

Here is my code :

`server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');
const { importSchema } = require('graphql-import');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = '/graphql';


const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: importSchema('./greet.graphql'),
  resolvers: require('./graphql/resolver'),
});

const app = express();
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, path });

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Server Hosted');
});
```

`greet.graphql`

```
type Query {
  greeting: String
}
```

`resolver.js`

```
const Query = {
  greeting: () => 'Hello World From NightDevs',
};

module.exports = { Query };
```

Not only this, but Ive tried this solution also - [Stackoverflow Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62290875/how-to-load-a-graphql-file-using-apollo-server)

But This doesn't work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me. package versions:

```
"apollo-server-express": "^2.12.0",
"graphql-import": "^0.7.1",
```

Example:

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const { importSchema } = require('graphql-import');
const path = require('path');

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: importSchema(path.resolve(__dirname, './greet.graphql')),
  resolvers: require('./resolver')
});

const app = express();
const graphqlEndpoint = '/graphql';
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, path: graphqlEndpoint });

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Server Hosted');
});
```

`greet.graphql`:

```
type Query {
  greeting: String
}
```

`resolver.js`:

```js
const Query = {
  greeting: () => 'Hello World From NightDevs',
};

module.exports = { Query };
```

Testing via `curl`:

```sh
curl 'http://localhost:8080/graphql' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8080' --data-binary '{"query":"query {\n  greeting\n}"}' --compressed
```

Get result:

```sh
{"data":{"greeting":"Hello World From NightDevs"}}
```